# Can I add lime at the same time when I spray Roundup?

Tags: lawn, weed-control, grass, growth, yard

I sprayed the weed killer roundup and wanted to know if I can also spread some lime at the same time to neutralize my acidic garden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! the glyphosate will still work. Here's what to look out for, though. Don't walk through any bed you've sprayed roundup (even spot sprayed) until all sprayed surfaces have dried over. Then you're good. Even a little bit on your  shoes can cause dead/discolored prints all over your lawn.

The easy way to avoid that without taking a break, is, of course, to spread the lime first, and then you can apply roundup right away.

Comment: Thanks should I till in the lime or just leave it on top? Also can I reseed right away or is there a waiting time?

Comment: @Joseph Wit: Depends which formulation of Round Up you used. You should also not disturb the sprayed plants for a minimum of 7 days, to give the product time to work back to the root.

Comment: once the roundup has completed it's job...  regarding the lime should I work it into the soil or just leave it on top

Comment: @JosephWit It will work it's way in within the year, but manually working it in will definitely speed the process.